# error to webclient in create ssl/tls secure channel c#

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, webclient, .net-4.7.2

I can not use `WebClient.UploadDataTaskAsync()`, because:

> System.Net.WebException: 'The request was aborted: Could not create
> SSL/TLS secure channel.'

This is my code:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);

webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Referer] = "https://d.easytrader.emofid.com/";
webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "application/json, text/plain, */*");
webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36");
webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json");
webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, authorization);

byte[] DataResive = await webClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync("https://cl3.emofid.com/easy/api/account/checkuser");
```

Comment: Which version of Windows, which version of .NET?

Comment: In what System is this code executed? Note that you have to set everything related to `ServicePointManager` before anything else, which includes the WebClient instance. -- Unrelated: this `Expect100Continue` you may want to set to `false`.

Comment: win 7 .net 4.7.2

Comment: Why are you using `WebClient`? You should use `HttpClient` instead.

Comment: There's the chance, since the System is outdated and doesn't receive security updates anymore, that you don't have required cipher suites.

Comment: `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);` This is a security disaster waiting no happen. **NEVER** omit certificate validation.

Comment: I do not need a valid certificate

Comment: I just want my request sent

Comment: I just want to be able to open this address https://d11.emofid.com/endpoint/prod/ with a web client

Comment: and https://cl3.emofid.com/easy/api/account/checkuser

Comment: In Windows 7, you can open the former, not the latter. -- Never use the User-Agent string of a recent Browser. You can use, e.g., FireFox 56 user-agent string. Otherwise, you're just asking for trouble. A bit different with the HttpClient version of .Net 5+.

Comment: @MohamadGhanbari "I do not need a valid certificate" **YES YOU DO** (bold, shouty-caps for extra emphasis): your code shows you're connecting to a publicly accessible Internet website, not an internal LAN or intranet website. Your software should _never_ blindly trust a public website's certificate - _no software_ should ever trust remote hosts like that.